# Firefox doesn't restore server-sent events connection

Tags: python, html, firefox, cherrypy, server-sent-events

Test case implemented with Python and CherryPy:

```
import cherrypy, time

class Root():

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return r'''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Server-sent events test</title>
  <style>html,body,#test{height:98%;}</style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      var source = new EventSource('gettime');
      source.addEventListener('time', function (event) {
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += event.data + "\n";
      });
      source.addEventListener('error', function (event){
        console.log('SSE error:', event);
        console.log('SSE state:', source.readyState);
      });
    }, false);
  </script>
  <textarea id="test"></textarea>
 </body>
</html>'''

    @cherrypy.expose
    def gettime(self):
        cherrypy.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/event-stream"
        def generator():
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
                yield "event: time\n" + "data: " + str(time.time()) + "\n\n"
        return generator()
    gettime._cp_config = {'response.stream': True}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0'})
    cherrypy.quickstart(Root())
```

After receiving some messages successfully I manually drop the connection, then in Firefox' web console appears JS Error: `The connection to http://localhost:8080/gettime was interrupted while the page was loading.`

According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/eventsource/), `Clients will reconnect if the connection is closed`, but Firefox doesn't. Error event handler reports that the `source` is in `CLOSED` state.

`CLOSED (numeric value 2)
The connection is not open, and the user agent is not trying to reconnect. Either there was a fatal error or the close() method was invoked.`
So there was a fatal error?

- In Chromium it works, error handler reports that the `source` is in `CONNECTING` (0) state (as it should) and connection is automatically restored within a few seconds
- Have tried Firefox 26, Firefox 24 ESR and Iceweasel 17 on Linux and Windows platforms, all the same
- Have checked raw protocol and headers, looks ok
- Have tried to add `retry: 3000` to each sent event
- Have tried to move JavaScript out of event listener and wrapping it into setTimeout

Comment: +2 only working Cherrypy/SSE example I've found on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=831392) is fixed in Firefox 36.

Comment: i'm having this issue again 7 years later

Answer (score 0):

The spec on this stuff is in flux and there is a number of open spec issues related to the reconnection behavior that the spec proposes.  I wouldn't rely on any specific reconnection behavior until the spec stabilizes a lot more than it has so far.