# How to stream data with Cherrypy

Tags: python, streaming, cherrypy, yield

The following code should send 4 lines of text to the browser, 1 line per second.

Instead the browser (I tried with Chrome and IE) waits 4 seconds and shows the 4 lines at the same time. The snippet shows two lines setting the header. I tried with both, but neither works.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import cherrypy
import time

class Root:

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'  # see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837460/firefox-doesnt-restore-server-sent-events-connection
        cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'         # see http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#how-streaming-output-works-with-cherrypy

        def streamer():
            for i in range(3):
                time.sleep(1)
                yield '{} {}\n'.format(time.asctime(), i+1)
                print(i)

            time.sleep(1)
            yield '{} Done'.format(time.asctime())

        return streamer()

    index._cp_config = {'response.stream': True}

cherrypy.quickstart(Root())
```

Comment: Need external streamer app for synchronous communication(s). you got delay but server always pushed data(s).

Comment: @SDilmac I don't understand your comment. I'm trying to do this: http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#streaming-the-response-body

Comment: Sorry  for status. i cant understand your questions. i got bad language.
Single request, 3 data group and single header. I am sorry for wasted your time. please accept my apologized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. It depends on the browser. For this sort of debugging use something like `curl -v` or `curl --trace-ascii -`.  It shows each line arriving with a timeout as you expect.  Should also work with firefox.

Comment: You are right, it works with Firefox! I did think about a problem with the browser, that's why I tried it with both Chrome and IE. It is an app that spends a few hours scanning the disk and populating a database. It used to stream the progress to Chrome. I haven't used in months, and now it doesn't stream anymore. Do you think some update in Chrome changed the behavior? Or did I break the app?

Comment: @stenci If it used to work in chrome and doesnt anymore, I imagine it's a safe bet that chrome has been "optimised" sadly.  The only way to reliably update web pages in this way is to use ajax, websockets, or send a refresh    timeout header, which unfortunately means a new connection on each refresh.

Comment: Oops... no, Chrome is not the problem. On Monday I tested the script on Ubuntu+Firefox and it worked, so I assumed the culprit was Chrome. Today I installed Firefox on Win7 and tested it, and it doesn't work. So, Win7+Anaconda fails, Ubuntu+stock Python works. Any suggestion? Should I ask the question again with more details?

Comment: I think you should revise your strategy and for example move to the modern websockets. even cherrypy says that streaming is not a good idea.

Comment: :) You are right, ... but this is an internal test tool that I only use once every few months. The stream with CherryPy (without Anaconda) is so easy that I always use it for quick and dirty cases. I was delaying the websocket implementation for when I really need it. I guess I will start from here: https://ws4py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sources/servertutorial/#cherrypy